# How to suppress warning messages in tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1?

Tags: bash, tar

On trying to tar files that are getting changed, I am receiving this message -
`tar: file changed as we read it.`
I am trying to suppress this warning message like this -

```
tar --warning=no-file-changed -zcvf testtar.tar.gz test.txt
```

then I get this error-
`` tar: unrecognized option `--warning=no-file-changed' ``  
I have also tried with this -

```
tar --ignore-failed-read -zcvf testtar.tar.gz test.txt
```

But still the message "file changed as we read it" was not suppressed.
Also, I know that I can redirect error messages like this -

```
tar -zcvf testtar2.tar.gz test.txt 2>/dev/null
```

but "file changed as we read it" is a warning (with exit code 1) and not fatal error (with exit code 2) and I only want to suppress warnings from appearing and not error messages.
Can someone please tell me if there is a way to suppress the warning messages only in tar 1.15.1?

EDIT-
`tar --version` gives this output - `tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1`

Comment: The "unrecognized option" error is interesting. What does `tar --version` output on that system?

Comment: tar --version gives this output -    tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1

Comment: And that's the same `tar` that complains about `--warning=no-file-changed`?

Comment: The `--warning` option was introduced in 1.23, which came out in 2010. Your version, 1.15.1 came out in 2004. Is there a reason you need to use such a positively ancient version? If that version were a human, it would be an adult now.

Comment: Have you considered filtering stderr with something like `tar -zcvf testtar2.tar.gz test.txt 2> >(grep -v 'file changed as we read it' >&2)`?

Comment: ```tar -zcvf testtar2.tar.gz test.txt 2> >(grep -v 'file changed as we read it' >&2)``` is suppressing "file changed as we read it" but for other errors like "Permission denied and Error exit delayed from previous errors" its getting hung and creating a tar file which cant be untarred. I want to redirect "file changed as we read it" and stdout to /dev/null and preserve other error messages with exit code of 2 which appears for genuine tar error messages. After running tar command I will get the exit code like c=$? and check if its 2. Can you kindly help me to frame the command for that?